# Do I have a bug in my grammar, or the parser-generation tool?

Tags: python, parsing, grammar, grako

The following is an EBNF-format (mostly - the actual syntax is documented [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/grako/3.4.3#expressions)) grammar that I am attempting to generate a parser for:

```
expr = lambda_expr_list $;

lambda_expr_list = [ lambda_expr_list "," ] lambda_expr;

lambda_expr = conditional_expr [ "->" lambda_expr ];

conditional_expr = boolean_or_expr [ "if" conditional_expr "else" conditional_expr ];

boolean_or_expr = [ boolean_or_expr "or" ] boolean_xor_expr;

boolean_xor_expr = [ boolean_xor_expr "xor" ] boolean_and_expr;

boolean_and_expr = [ boolean_and_expr "and" ] boolean_not_expr;

boolean_not_expr = [ "not" ] relation;

relation = [ relation ( "=="
                      | "!="
                      | ">"
                      | "<="
                      | "<"
                      | ">="
                      | [ "not" ] "in"
                      | "is" [ "not" ] ) ] bitwise_or_expr;

bitwise_or_expr = [ bitwise_or_expr "|" ] bitwise_xor_expr;

bitwise_xor_expr = [ bitwise_xor_expr "^" ] bitwise_and_expr;

bitwise_and_expr = [ bitwise_and_expr "&" ] bitwise_shift_expr;

bitwise_shift_expr = [ bitwise_shift_expr ( "<<"
                                          | ">>" ) ] subtraction_expr;

subtraction_expr = [ subtraction_expr "-" ] addition_expr;

addition_expr = [ addition_expr "+" ] division_expr;

division_expr = [ division_expr ( "/"
                                | "\\" ) ] multiplication_expr;

multiplication_expr = [ multiplication_expr ( "*"
                                            | "%" ) ] negative_expr;

negative_expr = [ "-" ] positive_expr;

positive_expr = [ "+" ] bitwise_not_expr;

bitwise_not_expr = [ "~" ] power_expr;

power_expr = slice_expr [ "**" power_expr ];

slice_expr = member_access_expr { subscript };

subscript = "[" slice_defn_list "]";

slice_defn_list = [ slice_defn_list "," ] slice_defn;

slice_defn = lambda_expr
           | [ lambda_expr ] ":" [ [ lambda_expr ] ":" [ lambda_expr ] ];

member_access_expr = [ member_access_expr "." ] function_call_expr;

function_call_expr = atom { parameter_list };

parameter_list = "(" [ lambda_expr_list ] ")";

atom = identifier
     | scalar_literal
     | nary_literal;

identifier = /[_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*/;

scalar_literal = float_literal
               | integer_literal
               | boolean_literal;

float_literal = point_float_literal
              | exponent_float_literal;

point_float_literal = /[0-9]+?\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\./;

exponent_float_literal = /([0-9]+|[0-9]+?\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.)[eE][+-]?[0-9]+/;

integer_literal = dec_integer_literal
                | oct_integer_literal
                | hex_integer_literal
                | bin_integer_literal;

dec_integer_literal = /[1-9][0-9]*|0+/;

oct_integer_literal = /0[oO][0-7]+/;

hex_integer_literal = /0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+/;

bin_integer_literal = /0[bB][01]+/;

boolean_literal = "true"
                | "false";

nary_literal = tuple_literal
             | list_literal
             | dict_literal
             | string_literal
             | byte_string_literal;

tuple_literal = "(" [ lambda_expr_list ] ")";

list_literal = "[" [ ( lambda_expr_list
                     | list_comprehension ) ] "]";

list_comprehension = lambda_expr "for" lambda_expr_list "in" lambda_expr [ "if" lambda_expr ];

dict_literal = "{" [ ( dict_element_list
                     | dict_comprehension ) ] "}";

dict_element_list = [ dict_element_list "," ] dict_element;

dict_element = lambda_expr ":" lambda_expr;

dict_comprehension = dict_element "for" lambda_expr_list "in" lambda_expr [ "if" lambda_expr ];

string_literal = /[uU]?[rR]?(\u0027(\\.|[^\\\r\n\u0027])*\u0027|\u0022(\\.|[^\\\r\n\u0022])*\u0022)/;

byte_string_literal = /[bB][rR]?(\u0027(\\[\u0000-\u007F]|[\u0000-\u0009\u000B-\u000C\u000E-\u0026\u0028-\u005B\u005D-\u007F])*\u0027|\u0022(\\[\u0000-\u007F]|[\u0000-\u0009\u000B-\u000C\u000E-\u0021\u0023-\u005B\u005D-\u007F])*\u0022)/;
```

The tool I'm using to generate the parser is [Grako](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/grako/3.4.3), which generates a modified Packrat parser that claims to support both direct and indirect left recursion.

When I run the generated parser on this string:

```
input.filter(e -> e[0] in ['t', 'T']).map(e -> (e.len().str(), e)).map(e -> '(Line length: ' + e[0] + ') ' + e[1]).list()
```

I get the following error:

```
grako.exceptions.FailedParse: (1:13) Expecting end of text. :
input.filter(e -> e[0] in ['t', 'T']).map(e -> (e.len().str(), e)).map(e -> '(Line length: ' + e[0] + ') ' + e[1]).list()
            ^
expr
```

Debugging has shown that the parser seems to get to the end of the first `e[0]`, then never backtracks to/reaches a point where it will try to match the `in` token.

Is there some issue with my grammar such that a left recursion-supporting Packrat parser would fail on it? Or should I file an issue on the Grako issue tracker?

Comment: Can you simplify grammar and statement to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 4):

It may be a bug in the grammar, but the error message is not telling you where it actually happens. What I always do after finishing a grammar is to embed *cut* (`~`) elements throughout it (after keywords like *if*, operators, opening parenthesis, everywhere it seems reasonable).

The *cut* element makes the Grako-generated parser commit to the option taken in the closest choice in the parse tree. That way, instead of having the parser fail at the start on an *if*, it will report failure at the expression it actually couldn't parse.

Some bugs in grammars are difficult to spot, and for that I just go through the parse trace to find out how far in the input the parser went, and why it decided it couldn't go further.

I will not use left-recursion on a PEG parser for professional work, though it may be fine for simpler, academic work.

```
boolean_or_expr = boolean_xor_expr {"or" boolean_xor_expr};
```

The associativity can then be handled in a semantic action.

Also see the discussion under [issue 49](https://bitbucket.org/apalala/grako/issue/49/bug-in-left-recursion) against Grako. It says that the algorithm used to support left recursion will not always produce the expected associativity in the resulting AST.

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding the cut elements. I suspect that will probably speed parsing up a bit as well, because right now it's pretty slow.

Comment: That said, it's looking like I'm probably after a bottom-up parser if I want to keep the grammatical rules left-recursive. Regarding your point about the associativity - I can't help but wonder what the point is of having Packrat support left-recursion if the associativity of the rules is not preserved. Wouldn't it be simpler to just say "You need a bottom-up parser for this"?

Comment: @Trey Left recursion makes it easier to write grammars for some languages. The lack of guarantees regarding associativity are not designed in, but a consequence of the algorithm used, and something the subject of research. Also note that the associativity you want will likely be preserved for your particular grammar.

Comment: Apologies for the delay on this; I've been busy with Uni.

Thanks for the clarification. Good to know. :)

I've refactored the grammar, adding the cut elements as you suggested (the new grammar is available at http://pastebin.com/eykU3V9K).

Comment: Given the same input string, the problem seems to be occurring within the list literal just after the first 'in' keyword.

The generated parser will parse the first element (the 't'), then the comma successfully. In an attempt to parse the second element (the 'T'), the parser descends down to the power_expr rule, where it invokes the first slice_expr rule and successfully parses the 'T'. It then fails to parse the '**' token, and backtracks to take power_expr's second option, invoking the slice_expr rule a second time.

Comment: The issue then manifests when the slice_expr rule attempts to invoke the member_access_expr rule, because for some reason there is already a FailedLeftRecursion entry in the memoization cache for the member_access_expr rule, preventing it from being invoked.

Can you shed any light on this?

Comment: Additionally, I've noticed that changing `power_expr = slice_expr "**" ~ power_expr | slice_expr;` to `power_expr = slice_expr [ "**" ~ power_expr ];` causes the parser to take an age to run (possibly due to catastrophic backtracking?). I would have thought the two were equivalent, since in the first form if the parser failed to match `"**"`, it would backtrack everything it's seen since the start of the `power_expr`, then try the second alternative? Am I missing something fundamental here?

Comment: @Tray could you post this as an issue in [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/apalala/grako). I'll take a look on the next pass through Grako.

Comment: @TreyBrisbane Did you post it there? You have a link?

Comment: The link is where it says "Bitbucket". https://bitbucket.org/apalala/grako/issues